# What is the easiest way to view all of the previous days changes with Tortoise SVN?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I want to see all changes by everyone in a visual GUI showing diffs. Is this possible with Tortoise SVN? If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter out the changes of the previous day in TortoiseSVN[image] see the from area. But not directly the diffs.

Comment: You may also select two revisions in this window, right-click and choose "Compare revisions" To see all the changes at once between those two revisions.

Answer (score 1):

From the context menu in Windows Explorer you can choose Show Log and then filter based on a "from" date and a "to" date. Just enter yesterdays date for both and then you'll see the changesets. You will have to then click on each to see the modified files and then select diff on each one to see the changes.